# sudo apt-get update fail on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, ubuntu-17.04

While running the `sudo apt-get update` on ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus, I am getting the following error. I have posted on the error lines. I wanted to install python libraries like matplotlib and tkinter which failed to installed because above command wasn't running succesfully. Please suggest me what to do.

```
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
Err:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:81 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Err:113 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::14 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Use AskUbuntu for this. SO is not the right place for this.

Comment: Was wondering if this is because 17.04 is no longer getting support and I was getting a prompt to update to 17.10

Comment: @AyushKumar Yes, this is it! See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) for instructions.

Comment: @YoanTournade Yes, I figured it out as I couldn't find any solution for this, so I upgraded to 17.10 yesterday. Turns out that 17.04 was no longer getting support from Ubuntu.

Comment: Followed this and was able to fix it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/999856/apt-get-update-fails-when-updating-from-17-04-to-17-10-after-eol-none-of-the-mi

Comment: in my case below link helped me. https://askubuntu.com/questions/999856/apt-get-update-fails-when-updating-from-17-04-to-17-10-after-eol-none-of-the-mi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

17.04 isn't getting further support from Ubuntu. So, the solution that worked for me was to upgrade it to 17.10 as none other solutions helped.

Answer (score 11):

you can solve it by: **just replace us.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com in /etc/apt/sources.list with old-releases.ubuntu.com and then you'll be able to finish updating.**

refer to [source 1](http://wimantis.ninja/fixing-ubuntu-17-04-apt-get-update-release-file-not-found/) and [ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2382832)

it work for me

Comment: Did that, but it didn't worked for me. I eventually upgraded to 17.10

Answer (score 9):

In my case:

```
sed -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list 
sed -e 's/security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: results in `W: Failed to fetch http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'` got include `us.` in the search pattern

Comment: somehow the find-and-replace didn't work well for me and encountered similar issue. So opened /etc/apt/sources.list, and replaced it manually to make the URLs as http://old-releases.ubuntu.com instead of http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com and update command started working well.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to download some of the packages by doing the following:

I had to replace "us.archive.ubuntu.com" and "security.ubuntu.com" in /etc/apt/sources.list WITH "old-releases.ubuntu.com" and then I was able to finish downloading some of the packages, like Ayush Kumar said.

For the other updates that were listed by my Hosting company, Linode, I used the following:

I had to use the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag with sudo apt-get update.

`sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated`

Then I was able to finish updating.