# linode | ubuntu | sudo apt-get update | mirror 404 error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, linode, ubuntu-16.10

On Linode (Ubuntu 16.10), after enabling UFW firewall via

```
sudo ufw allow OpenSSH
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow in "Apache Full"
```

(though I'm not completely sure the firewall setup is the source of my issues...)

`sudo apt-get update` is giving me the following message:

```
Ign:1 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Ign:2 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease
Ign:3 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease
Err:4 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ****:****:*::****:**** 80]
Err:5 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ****:****:*::****:**** 80]
Err:6 http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ****:****:*::****:**** 80]
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: ****:***:****::** 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

The source file `/etc/apt/source.list` :

```
# deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted

# deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security multiverse
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get dist-update` to no avail (also gives 404 errors).

I've also done `unset http_proxy` and `unset https_proxy`;

`apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update` - it still fails when using IPv4

I can `ping 8.8.8.8` just fine.

...nothing's worked yet. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You are going to need to allow port `53` and `123` in your UFW settings ..  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers.  OpenSSH is `22` by default and Apache is `80` `443` and `8080` by default.

Comment: @Zak I tried `sudo ufw allow 123/udp` and `sudo ufw allow 53/udp`, no change

Comment: More material --> https://serverfault.com/questions/468907/ufw-blocking-apt

Comment: I followed all of those instructions as well. No dice. I also tried disabling the firewall and doing apt-get, nothing.

Comment: That probably means your networking isn't set up correctly --  Have you tried a `wget` as in `cd ~; wget http://google.com` and see what the response is ..  What about a `curl` command?  `curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null`  -- You can also try a `dig` command.  `dig google.com ns`  --  My bet is one or all of these fail ..

Comment: `wget http://google.com`: I can connect but permission is denied to edit index.html (as expected).
`curl -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://www.google.com/" -o /dev/null`: OUTPUT -> 200
`dig google.com ns`: worked as well

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: You must be fun at parties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Linode Support:

It looks like you are using an Ubuntu versions that's reached its end of life status.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

You can reference the following link to see if you are able to update this in another manner. The other option is deploy an updated Ubuntu image for your server and copy your data over to the new disk.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrade

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this as well. But I got it working.

I had to replace "us.archive.ubuntu.com" and "security.ubuntu.com" in `/etc/apt/sources.list` WITH "old-releases.ubuntu.com" and then I was able to finish downloading some of the packages, like Ayush Kumar said in [sudo apt-get update fail on Ubuntu 17.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377901/sudo-apt-get-update-fail-on-ubuntu-17-04/49017094#49017094).

For the other updates that were listed by my Hosting company, Linode, I used the following:

I had to use the `--allow-unauthenticated` flag with sudo apt-get update.

`sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated`

Then I was able to finish updating.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been driving me mad for days, ended up resolving it by just completely uninstalling ufw and cleaning up any leftover resources and then doing a clean install again with the same port rules.

First disable ufw:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Remove the package:

```
sudo apt-get remove ufw
```

Purge previous ufw configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge ufw
```

Remove unusued packages and clean the local repository:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

Re-install ufw again and set up the rules again to your liking:

```
sudo apt install ufw
```

I have no idea what caused the initial install and set up to break, didn't change anything at all.. strange.